# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

Tags: apache-flink

I'm able to run my Flink job from IntelliJ without a problem, however when I try to run it on flink standalone ...

```
wget ... flink-1.4.0-bin-hadoop27-scala_2.11.tgz
tar xf flink-1.4.0-bin-hadoop27-scala_2.11.tgz
./flink-1.4.0/bin/start-local.sh
./flink-1.4.0/bin/flink run ../mypath/target/messagehub-to-s3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
```

I get the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFsFactory.create(HadoopFsFactory.java:112)
```

I'm using the maven shade plugin (based on [dataArtisans example](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/pom.xml)) to create my jar file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- This list contains all dependencies of flink-dist
                                Everything else will be packaged into the fat-jar
                                -->
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-annotations</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-curator-recipes</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-avro_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-batch_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala-shell_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-python</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-jmx</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.11</exclude>


                                <!-- Also exclude very big transitive dependencies of Flink
                                WARNING: You have to remove these excludes if your code relies on other
                                versions of these dependencies.
                                -->

                                <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-compiler</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-reflect</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-actor_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-remote_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-slf4j_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>io.netty:netty-all</exclude>
                                <exclude>io.netty:netty</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.avro:avro</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-collections:commons-collections</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-compress</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.tukaani:xz</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.objenesis:objenesis</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang</exclude>
                                <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12</exclude>
                                <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-math</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.json</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations</exclude>
                                <exclude>stax:stax-api</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.typesafe:config</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.github.scopt:scopt_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-io:commons-io</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-cli:commons-cli</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.apache.flink:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <!-- exclude shaded google but include shaded curator -->
                                    <exclude>org/apache/flink/shaded/com/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>web-docs/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.ibm.cloud.flink.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I'm using the S3 hadoop Flink fs library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-s3-fs-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

My project is on github: https://github.com/ibm-cloud-streaming-retail-demo/flink-on-iae-messagehub-to-s3

I think a different set of jars are getting loaded running standalone.  Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can generate a Flink Quickstart project using:

```
mvn archetype:generate                               
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.flink             
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=flink-quickstart-java      
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.4.0
```

This is cleaner and safer than copying `pom.xml` files from existing projects.

As far as I could see on Github, your job uses the BucketingSink. As of Flink
1.4.0, this sink has a direct dependency to Hadoop's FileSystem class [1].
However, you are including `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` as a dependency; this is a Flink
file system with shaded Hadoop dependencies, which won't work with the current
BucketingSink implementation.

The exception that you are seeing hints a class loading problem [2]. I suspect
that you have Hadoop classes in your user jar, which conflict with the ones
coming from Flink. What you can try is to remove all Hadoop dependencies in your
pom.xml, or in the `flink-conf.yaml` you can try to set `classloader.resolve-order: parent-first` [3].

[1] https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.4/flink-connectors/flink-connector-filesystem/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.java#L1118

[2] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#x-cannot-be-cast-to-x-exceptions

[3] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#configuring-classloader-resolution-order